# jQuery adiciona classe, mas não remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando esse código para adicionar uma classe para deixar um menu fixo. O problema é que ela não esta removendo a classe depois. Como proceder?

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('nav').offset().top) {
    $('nav:not(.fixo)').addClass('fixo');
  } else {
    $('nav.fixo').removeClass('fixo');
  }
});
```

Comment: Parece funcionar bem: https://jsfiddle.net/zo9x5v8e/

Comment: aqui ele adiciona a classe mas não remove, não sei o porque disso

Comment: seria bom se postasse também o HTML

Comment: parece que ele funciona mas depois de atribuir a classe fixo e rolar a pagina pra cima ai já não funciona, sera que não esta reconhecendo o scrollUp ?

Comment: coloque um console.log antes da linha $('nav.fixo').removeClass('fixo'); para descobrir se ao menos o código chegou até ali

Comment: Coloca o HTML... pf.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vc pode usar `$("#id_campo").removeAttr("class");`

Comment: também não funcionou